# how can you split data into individual variables and assign it to three different dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

Attached is a CSV file that contains rows of data describing the attack information from a particular IP address. The first column is the IP address, the second the country of origin, the third the number of attack attempts and the fourth represents the number of unique user names used in the attacks. For example, IP address 222.234.0.57 is in the Republic of Korea and attempted to log in 599 times using 580 invalid user names. Apparently some of the user names were used more than once.

Your objective is to open the file, read it line by line, split the data into individual variables and assign it to three different dictionaries. The key for each dictionary is the IP address. Each dictionary contains different values that can be associated with the key (IP). For example, use the IP to look up the coutry of origin in one dictionary, the number of attacks in another and the number of unique user names in the third dictionary.

Provide a menu that allows the user to select what it is they would like to do. They can:

- Find the number of attacks associated with an IP address
- Find the country of origin for an IP
- Find the number of different invalid user names tried
- Quit

HELLPPP :)))

Comment: There's no attachment here. And anyway, we're not a code-writing service. Take a look at [ask], then edit your question to include your attempt to solve the problem. After that, tell us what's specifically wrong with your implementation.

Comment: This is not a homework-doing service. Anyway, you can probably already find the necessary questions and answers to complete your assignment on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question)[https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.